# Odoo 13 : Loading never end when updating module (when set default field or set store=True in model that has so many data)

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, erp, odoo-13

let's say that i have so many data in hr_attendance module.
in that module has field like this :

```
distance_string = fields.Char(string='Distance', compute='_compute_range')
```

then i change distance_field and add new field to :

```
distance_string = fields.Char(string='Distance', compute='_compute_range', store=True)
outside_range= fields.Selection([('no','no'),('yes','Yes')], string="Out of Range", default='no')
```

the problem is because of so many datas in my model (maybe 270000+ datas). When i update the module (hr_attendance) in app menu in ODOO13, it takes so much loading time to install and then it always fail.
I assumed that because of so many data in my model, when i only add **outside_range** field without **default='no'** it works fine.

my question is how to handle this condition (when i need to set **store=True** and add **default=''** in model that has so many data)?

thanks for your help

Comment: *note : It works when i update this module that has less data

Comment: it fails like nothing happen and server restarted by itself. i have 2 servers, dev and production. 
in dev server there's only less data (maybe only 100) data. In production server has 270000+ data. 

when i set default = 'no' in the field all of the data will set default field (even the existing data). I think the problem is the system that cannot update 270000 data when updating the module. I dont know how to fix it like only set default for new data (after update) and null for existing data (before update)